# Excel Macro for Sorting Wire sizes from AutoCAD

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, autocad

So what I'm trying to do is I have a wire number report from AutoCAD and I'm taking the wire numbers from the report and transferring them into the wire label printer software for our shop to print.

Making the report is easy; Using the printer software and printing the labels is easy.

It's the difficulty of sorting the wire labels in the excel file that's giving me problems. I can manually sort the wire numbers into their own files just fine but I'm ultimately trying to automate this part of the process.

So I've uploaded an image of raw data next to the 6 sorted and finished excel files.

[image]

As you can see the report separates by wire the wire tag from AutoCAD which is just by wire color and wire gauge. The wire color doesn't matter. Each Wire size has it's own mark tube wire label except for the 16 and 18 gauge; they both can fit in the 3.2mm tube but for simplicity sake I've just kept them separate anyway.

So each set of wire labels will need to go to their separate file for further processing by the printer. They will eventually be changed to .csv files but those are a pain to work with so I'm doing that part last and it's simple to do anyway.

```
WireLabels - 18AWG - 3.2mm .xlsm
WireLabels - 16AWG - 3.2mm .xlsm 
WireLabels - 14AWG - 3.6mm .xlsm 
WireLabels - 12AWG - 4.2mm .xlsm 
WireLabels - 10AWG - 5.0mm .xlsm 
WireLabels - 8AWG - 6.0mm .xlsm 
WireLabels - 6AWG - 8.0mm .xlsm
```

I'm basically trying to figure out how to loop down through the column and sort each set of wire numbers to their own file.

It's pretty simple to do with a set range of numbers but with differing reports from AutoCAD from project to project I can't set specific ranges like a range from A5 to A8 and that's where I'm stuck... I've been trying to select a range down to the blank cell past each bit of numbers but can't past that point.

ANY insight would be amazing. Thanks!

**Can you please show your existing code or what you've tried thus far?**

```
Sub NewSheets()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'This is is just to have a place to send the groups of numbers for now.
'They will eventually go to their own new workbooks

'
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub

Sub wires14()
  Range("A64:A69").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

     Dim wb As Workbook

    '// Set as reference to a new, one-sheet workbook.                              //
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    With wb
        '// Skip selecting the sheet, just reference it explicitly and copy it after//
        '// the blank sheet in the new wb.                                          //
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet3").Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        '// Kill alerts, delete the blank sheet in the new wb and turn alerts back on//
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Worksheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        '// SaveAs the new workbook to whatever path and close.                     //
        .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Public\Desktop\" & "14AWG - 4.6mm"
        .Close False
    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=3, columnOffset:=3).Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

SO I have a button that can sort the selection and save it as file but automatically going through, finding, and selecting
without specifically calling out a set range of cells is where I got stuck.

This bit I tried can select the specific wire number and copy the following numbers to a new sheet but, again, it only will grab the specified range
and wouldn't be able to deal with a changing range.

```
Sub NewSheets()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'This is is just to have a place to send the groups of numbers for now.
'They will eventually go to their own new workbooks

'
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub

Sub LoopThruA()

  Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="_18", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Range(Selection, "A32").Select
     Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

  End Sub
```

**Also, are BLU 18 and BLK 16 going to be the only wires that share a workbook?**

6 gauge, 8, gauge, 10 gauge, 12 gauge, and 14 gauge will all have their own workbook.
16 gauge, 18 gauge, and ALL other tags that aren't mentioned above will be on the same workbook.
This is the case because 'cable' labels and much larger gauge wires will use the 3.2mm tubes strung through a zip tie and simply wrapped around.

**Will all these wire numbers always be in the same order (I understand the number of rows will change).**

The order will always be alphabetical/numerical based on the "(Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_12_MTW" section header
So an example order would be

```
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_12_MTW 
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_16_MTW
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_16_THHN_FW
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_18_MTW
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_2_MTW   (2 gauge wire)
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_2-0_MTW (2 ought wire)
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_4_MTW
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLK_6_MTW
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLU_18_MTW
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:BLU_18_THHN_FW
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:CABLE
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:FIELDWIRE
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:RED_18_MTW
                (Wire Label)Wire Layer:WHT_18_MTW
```

**If not the same order, will the text in their description boxes change?**

The first part(LEFT) of the text will NOT change "(Wire Label)Wire Layer:".

**Are these the only wire labels you'll ever have to do this for, or could there be others?**

With different colors there can be the same size wire but they will all go to the same new workbook together.
There are 25 different wire gauge designations we use and a small assortment of other wire label markers
 such as "Cable" "Cable Trunk" "FieldWires" "_Multi_WIRE" and "Multiconductor"

The wire sizes we use are as follows.

```
18
16
14
12
10
8
6
4   (4 gauge)
4-0 (4 ought)
3   (3 gauge)
3-0 (3 ought, etc...)
2
2-0
1
1-0
250
300
350
400
500
600
700
750
800
900
1000
```

Each number will have a trailing designation such as _MTW or _THHN_FW.

And the possible colors if it matters are...

```
BLK
BLU
BRN
GRN
ORG
RED
WHT-BLU
WHT
YEL
```

**Is it possible that there might be no rows at all for a specific wire label?**

Nope, if there aren't any wires on a wire layer it wont be on the report.

**CODE EDIT/UPDATE**
So this is what we have working for now. It works. It's not perfect but it does the job.

```
 Option Explicit

Sub DivideWireLabels()




Dim i As Long, j As Long, K As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook


Workbooks("OpenAndRunWireLabel SortTool.xls").Activate

'Add a worksheet for each category
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 16-18 & All Others"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 14 AWG - 3_6mm"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 12 AWG - 4_2mm"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 10 AWG - 5_0mm"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 8 AWG - 6_0mm"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 6 AWG - 8_0mm"
End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

'Loop thru the column




For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Find the wire layer cell

    If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "Wire Layer") > 0 Then

'if the wire layer is there, make a new sheet for it

        If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_14_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 14 AWG - 3_6mm")
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_12_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 12 AWG - 4_2mm")
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_10_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 10 AWG - 5_0mm")
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_8_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 8 AWG - 6_0mm")
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_6_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 6 AWG - 8_0mm")
        Else
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 16-18 & All Others")
        End If

'Take the data and put it in one of the new sheets

        For j = i + 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If Trim(Cells(j, 1).Value) <> "" Then
                K = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                If Trim(sht.Cells(K, 1).Value) = "" Then
                    Cells(j, 1).Copy
                    sht.Cells(K, 1).PasteSpecial
                Else
                    Cells(j, 1).Copy
                    sht.Cells(K + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
                End If
            Else
                i = j
                Exit For
            End If
Next j

End If

Next i

'Clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False


'delete sheets 2 and 3
Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
    Dim L As Long, M As Long
    M = Sheets.Count

    For L = M To 1 Step -1
        t = Sheets(L).Name
        If t = "Sheet2" Or t = "Sheet3" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Sheets(L).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next L






'Create a workbook for each new worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        Set wb = ws.Application.Workbooks.Add
        ws.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
        wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\" & ws.Name, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        Set wb = Nothing
    End If
Next ws

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True


   Dim x As Variant
    Dim Path As String

    ' Set the Path variable equal to the path of your program's installation
    Path = "C:\Program Files\Nisca Corporation\M-1ProVPC\MKP5PC.exe"

    x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3XCU.png

Comment: Can you please show your existing code or what you've tried thus far? Also, are BLU 18 and BLK 16 going to be the only wires that share a workbook? Will all these wire numbers always be in the same order (I understand the number of rows will change). If not the same order, will the text in their description boxes change? Are these the only wire labels you'll ever have to do this for, or could there be others? Is it possible that there might be no rows at all for a specific wire label? Lots of questions that need to be answered before you can write this out.

Comment: I've answered your questions as specifically as possible in the post. The code I've tried so far is minimal and fairly basic.

Comment: Great responses - and thank you for providing your code. Give me a bit and I'll provide you a solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so my understanding is that you're creating 6 new workbooks - 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, and everything else that doesn't fall into those categories. Fortunately the worksheet you're working with is easily setup for one loop through column A - all you have to do is figure out which worksheet to place the data on.

At the end, every worksheet that isn't the original (Sheet1) has a new workbook made for it. **Please note, I did not test the saving new workbooks portion**.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DivideWireLabels()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

'Add a worksheet for each category
With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - All Others"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 14 AWG - 3.6mm"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 12 AWG - 4.2mm"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 10 AWG - 5.0mm"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 8 AWG - 6.0mm"
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "WireLabels - 6 AWG - 8.0mm"
End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "Wire Layer") > 0 Then

        If InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_14_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 14 AWG - 3.6mm")
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_12_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 12 AWG - 4.2mm")
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_10_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 10 AWG - 5.0mm")
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_8_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 8 AWG - 6.0mm")
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(i, 1).Value, "_6_") > 0 Then
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - 6 AWG - 8.0mm")
        Else
            Set sht = Worksheets("WireLabels - All Others")
        End If

        For j = i + 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" Then
                k = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                If sht.Cells(k, 1).Value = "" Then
                    Cells(j, 1).Copy
                    sht.Cells(k, 1).PasteSpecial
                Else
                    Cells(j, 1).Copy
                    sht.Cells(k + 1, 1).PasteSpecial
                End If
            Else
                i = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

    End If
Next i

'Clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Create a workbook for each new worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        Set wb = ws.Application.Workbooks.Add
        ws.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
        wb.SaveAs "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\" & ws.Name, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        Set wb = Nothing
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That's given me a good start. Walking through it it weirdly loops through just fine with the 12awg, but then everything else gets put on the 14 awg sheet. For some reason it doesn't see the blank cell after the 2nd loop through the data. It's so close! Thank you for your help! I will look back at it again in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: @PotatoBrado So there mustn't be a blank cell separating them, I guess instead you could have it look for "Section" and have that be in the end point instead, but it might bring over whatever this empty character is in the cell above it.

Comment: You were right! The blanks had a space in them for some reason. I was told that anytime when checking for blanks I need to TRIM the cell that's being checked beforehand because there might be spaces. Not sure why, could be just the way AutoCAD formats the report's "Empty" cells.

Comment: Thanks again! I was able to get it all to work with your help! Updated code has been provided in the original text.